# Hop mix on the sides of the fermentation bucket - is this safe?

Tags: fermentation

I recently opened my fermentation chamber to do a hydrometer check and noticed the hop bits are stuck to the sides of the bucket and no longer on the wort.

Want to ask if this is safe? Or is it a prime location for unwanted bacteria to grow?

Thank you

https://ibb.co/r2TK9YM

Answer (score 2):

That stuff is mostly yeast and protein from the active fermentation.  Its called [krausen](https://beercreation.com/what-is-krausen/). Its nothing to be concerned about.  I'd be concerned if it wasn't there post ferment!

Answer (score 1):

It is fine this happens all the time, it is to be expected.